# Concatenar dados de uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

tenho a seguinte instrução sql:

```
SELECT a.alunonome AS aluno, 
           m.materianome AS disciplina, 
           AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
                 WHEN 1 THEN n.nota
                 ELSE null
               END) AS bim1,
           AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
                 WHEN 2 THEN n.nota
                 ELSE null
               END) AS bim2,
           AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
                 WHEN 3 THEN n.nota
                 ELSE null
               END) AS bim3,
           AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
                 WHEN 4 THEN n.nota
                 ELSE null
               END) AS bim4
      FROM notas n
     INNER JOIN materias m ON m.materiaid = n.materiaid
     INNER JOIN alunos a ON a.alunoid = n.alunoid
     GROUP BY n.materiaid, n.alunoid, a.alunonome, m.materianome
```

ele me retorna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço pra concatenar o id da nota ficando assim:

```
ALUNO   |DISCIPLINA     |id1|bim1|id2|bim2|id3|bim3|id4|bim4
GUSTAVO |BANCO DE DADOS |1  |7   |2  |7   |3  |7   |4  |8
```

id da nota e na frente a nota fazer isso para o 4 bimestres.
Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Veja bem, o campo de nota do bimestre pode ser composto por mais de um registro. Você gostaria de mostrar todos?

Comment: queria mostrar todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a função `GROUP_CONCAT` com um `CASE`:

```
SELECT a.alunonome AS aluno,
       m.materianome AS disciplina,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE n.notabimestre
                      WHEN 1 THEN notaid
                    END) AS notaidbim1,
       AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
             WHEN 1 THEN n.nota
             ELSE null
           END) AS bim1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE n.notabimestre
                      WHEN 2 THEN notaid
                    END) AS notaidbim2,
       AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
             WHEN 2 THEN n.nota
             ELSE null
           END) AS bim2,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE n.notabimestre
                      WHEN 3 THEN notaid
                    END) AS notaidbim3,
       AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
             WHEN 3 THEN n.nota
             ELSE null
           END) AS bim3,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE n.notabimestre
                      WHEN 4 THEN notaid
                    END) AS notaidbim4,
       AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
             WHEN 4 THEN n.nota
             ELSE null
           END) AS bim4
  FROM notas n
 INNER JOIN materias m ON m.materiaid = n.materiaid
 INNER JOIN alunos a ON a.alunoid = n.alunoid
 GROUP BY n.materiaid, n.alunoid, a.alunonome, m.materianome
```

> [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
>
> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Em tradução livre:

> Essa função retorna a string resultante da concatenação de valores não-nulos em um agrupamento. Ela retornará NULL caso não existam valores não-nulos.

Comment: caraca Sorack tu é ninja. Era isso mesmo que estava precisando. Nunca ouvi falar de GROUP_CONCAT valeu mesmo a ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.alunonome AS aluno, 
       m.materianome AS disciplina,
       **campoID-DaNota as id1,**
       AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
             WHEN 1 THEN n.nota
             ELSE null
           END) AS bim1,
```

**campoID-DaNota2 as id2,**
           AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
                 WHEN 2 THEN n.nota
                 ELSE null
               END) AS bim2,
**campoID-DaNota3 as id3,**
           AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
                 WHEN 3 THEN n.nota
                 ELSE null
               END) AS bim3,
**campoID-DaNota4 as id4,**
           AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
                 WHEN 4 THEN n.nota
                 ELSE null
               END) AS bim4
      FROM notas n
     INNER JOIN materias m ON m.materiaid = n.materiaid
     INNER JOIN alunos a ON a.alunoid = n.alunoid
     GROUP BY n.materiaid, n.alunoid, a.alunonome, m.materianome